# Is .net core 5.0 production ready for azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0

In the azure portal for an app service you can now choose .Net 5 (Early access). What does the early access mean? Is it ready for production or should we wait?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ### Limitations of Early Access
>
> An Early Access runtime has full platform support and full fidelity of
> features. In other words, they behave just like every other runtime
> supported by App Service.
>
> Early Access does have an impact on cold-start performance and build
> times (if build is happening on App Service):
>
> #### Cold-start performanc impact
>
> An app using an Early Access runtime will have a slower initialization
> time compared to an app using a built-in runtime. Based on our testing
> the P95 impact is ~30 seconds with the average impact being <10
> seconds. This impact applies once per instance and should not be
> observed on subsequent application restarts as long as they happen on
> the same instance.
>
> #### Build performance impact
>
> An app using an Early Access runtime will have a slower build time
> compared to an app using a built-in runtime. Based on our testing the
> P95 impact on build is ~60 seconds with the average impact being <20
> seconds. This impact applies once per instance and should not be
> observed on subsequent builds as long as they happen on the same
> instance.

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/early_access.md